# How to change layout of an activity on the fly?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I want to create an app that at the start the user chooses a portrait or landscape mode and uses that mode from then on. Since its a game, the user can change it when he/she starts a new game. I wrote the following test code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    Button landscape = new Button(this);
    Button portrait  = new Button(this);
    landscape.setText("LandScape");
    landscape.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setupLandscape();
        }
    });
    portrait.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setupPortrait();
        }
    });
    portrait.setText("Portrait");
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.addView(landscape);
    ll.addView(portrait);
    setContentView(ll);
}

public void setupLandscape(){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    setContentView(ll);
}

public void setupPortrait(){
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"Portrait",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
}
```

}

However when I press the landscape button nothing happens. The layout is not reset to something else. So what am I doing wrong? Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: if Created two layouts, it should be automatic. When the user rotates the device, the activity is recreated and it should use the layout that fits the orientation.  Keeping it there is another matter, but simply trying to change layouts on the fly has no effect.

Comment: after orientation changes, your activity is destroyed and created again, it calls onCreate() method again--in which you orientation is restored back to portrait. That's why nothing happens. You should use `Bundle` object to remember orientation user selected.

Comment: Another way, then to do what I want is to spawn another activity, right?

Comment: I forgot to say that you were right. Also I tried, and was effectively able to solve it by spawning a different activity. Thanks for the help.